# Changing a Outputlink value based on a picklist value

Tags: visualforce

I want to know if I can do this in a visual force page, So i have a picklist value and a link inside the same visual force page. What I need to do is depending on what the user chooses within a picklist the outputlink value should change.

My project involves creating a registration page with a required (via validation) picklist field called "preferred language" now this field would be responsible on determining what page the user would land on if they clicked on the "privacy policy" or "terms" links within the vfp(UK,FR,etc.).

I haven't made some code involving the logic behind it yet since i'm pretty new with vfps.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.. Please visit our help center http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this avoiding the round-trip to the server (that takes a noticeable amount of time and can make a page feel sluggish):

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LeadSource}" onchange="change(this);"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:outputLink html-data-when="Web" style="display: none"
                value="http://google.com">Google</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:outputLink html-data-when="Other" style="display: none"
                value="http://bbc.co.uk">BBC</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:form>
<script>
function change(select) {
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
       var link = links[i];
       var when = link.getAttribute('data-when');
       if (when) link.style.display = (when == select.value) ? 'inline' : 'none';
   }
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

The links have an extra attribute added which is the picklist value that they should be shown for and JavaScript sets the CSS display property accordingly when the picklist value changes.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. simply create multiple `outputlink` and display them based on `picklist` condition.

```
<apex:form id="frm">
  <apex:pageMessages/>
         <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
                 Search By Month and Day<br />
                 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!currentMonth}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="frm"/>
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!monthsList}"/>
                 </apex:selectList>
                 <apex:outputlink value="www.google.com" rendered="{!currentMonth == 'Jan'}" />
                 <apex:outputlink value="http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/" rendered="{!currentMonth == 'Feb'}" />
         </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

or you can try another solution but this is little bit complex

```
<apex:form id="frm">
      <apex:pageMessages/>
             <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
                     Search By Month and Day<br />
                     <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!currentMonth}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="frm"/>
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!monthsList}"/>
                     </apex:selectList>
                     <apex:outputlink value="{!if(currentMonth == 'Jan', "www.google.com",if(currentMonth == 'feb',http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/,''))}" />

             </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

**Note:** there may be some compile time error exist in this code because I don't test this.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two good answers, but i went with a more simple answer (minimal coding), Im not sure if this would make the vfp feel sluggish since Im only testing with chrome developer tools as a salesforce1 app..

encased in an outputpanel with an actionsupport for the picklist field.

and just create each line with different conditions..

code snippet for future references

```
    <apex:actionRegion>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 right" style="float: right">
                        {!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Preferred__c.Label}*<apex:inputField value="{!account.Preferred__c}" style="font-size:13pt"><br/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ajaxrequest" />
                        </apex:inputField>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </apex:actionRegion>

                    <apex:outputPanel id='ajaxrequest'>    
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == '',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageUS" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'English (US)',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageUS" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'English (UK)',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageUK" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Spanish',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageES" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Mandarin',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageCMN" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Arabic',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageARA" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Russian',true,false)}" value="/apex/TermsOfUsePageRU" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Terms_Link}</apex:outputLink>

                                <a>and </a>

                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == '',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageUS" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>     
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'English (US)',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageUS" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'English (UK)',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageUK" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Spanish',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageES" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Mandarin',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageCMN" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Arabic',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageARA" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(account.Preferred__c == 'Russian',true,false)}" value="/apex/PrivacyPolicyPageRU" style="color:white; font-family:FuturaBook; font-weight:bolder">{!$Label.Create_New_Prospect_Privacy_Policy_Link}</apex:outputLink>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
```

The problem with my code though is that if i get redirected to the page from the outputlink and i go back, i will lose all field values for that page so my conditions would break

This is another question though, thanks for the fast reply !